# lpq: "hplj1320n is not ready"

Tags: arch-linux, printing, cups

Via SSH I'm logged into a Linux system (Arch) where the user says that he cannot print, even after a restart:

```
$ lpq
hplj1320n is not ready
no entries
```

From the CUPS web interface

- *Status:* Paused - "Filter failed"
- *Driver:* HP LaserJet 1320n hpijs, 3.15.2 (color, 2-sided printing)
- *Connection:* hp:/net/hp_LaserJet_1320_series?ip=192.168.2.2
- *Defaults:* job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=two-sided-long-edge

*Any idea how to fix this?* (from the command line)

I've seen that others solve the issue by clearing space on the HDD, but there is more than 200 GB of free space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the printer working again:

```
# cupsenable hplj1320n
```

Changing [ErrorPolicy](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.6/ref-printers-conf.html#ErrorPolicy) from the default `stop-printer` to `retry-current-job` prevents CUPS from deactivating the printer on error. This can be done via the web interface:

[image]